# Format pl_PL prices with CurrencyCode for ISO 4217

Tags: java

I need to format a price (as `BigDecimal`) to the polish currency format based on ISO 4217. This format should always have 2 decimals according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes and according to my acceptance criterias.

So I have the Java-Locale object for pl_PL and the related `CurrencyUnit 985` from `ISO 4217`, which I can see in the debugger. Now i have some issues when I want to format the following prices:

- 12.34000 => 12.34 (ok)
- 12.500 => 12.5 (not ok, expected is 12.50)
- 12.000 => 12 (not ok, expected is 12.00)

So I did some debugging and I discovered that Java read the `pl_PL` related pricing `DecimalPattern` from the class `FormatData_pl_PL.java`, where it is defined as the following:

```
{ "NumberPatterns",
new String[] {
"#,##0.###;-#,##0.###", // decimal pattern
"#,##0.## \u00A4;-#,##0.## \u00A4", // currency pattern
"#,##0%" // percent pattern
}
},
```

The pattern above will be used in this context:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) format;
String pattern = getSimplePattern(locale, currency);
decimalFormat.applyPattern(pattern);
return decimalFormat.format(price);
```

So the given currency pattern seems not to be correct. According to `ISO 4217` it should be `"#,##0.00"`, isn´t it?

How can I handle this issue?